# How can I identify source code from binary data without using -T/-B?

Tags: perl

I want to use binmode on binary files in Perl. So how can I know the file at hand is binary or text?

That means first I'd read full file to know if it is in binary or text then rewind the FP with binmode set if it is binary.

Since Perl -B/-T checks only a beginning block of text, it usually classifies pdf as text file(the source code could be hiding in any extension like .gif,.pdf etc). So I'd  need to read full file data to decide if it is binary or text file.

I've heard that any source code file( .pl,.c,.php etc) will not contain invisible characters like 0x0-0x1f and 0xff onwards.

Can I check every byte to be in this range to declare whether or not it is a source code file?

Comment: Why not just use the file extension?

Comment: After my website was hacked, I'm writing a program to catch such hacking codes injected in any file format. Because by changing .htaccess rules in website a gif,pdf file can be executed like a php script.

Comment: Ah, user uploaded files. Definite cause for this.

Comment: What kind of files are you expected to be uploaded? Are you asking for text only? Images only?

Comment: Hackers can inject files through some hacks that we also don't know but due to some or other vulnerabilities. I was surprised to  find a hidden php hack code in a zip file(.zip) uploaded from document upload facility.

Comment: A common heuristic is to look for null (zero) bytes, and declare the file binary if you find any.

Comment: The only reasonable response to being hacked is to restore a known-good backup on an updated and hardened clean install. Now you understand why you spent all this time and effort on backups and version control.

Comment: I've the backups. But you lose some data when you restore.

Comment: why not always use `binmode`?

Comment: @ikegami oh yes I couldn't think of this! But what'd happen in case of text file on windows? I think unix text files will not have \n expanded to \n\r's. That'd do for me as \n or \r are both whitespace. Please tell me how it will matter if I use binmode for text files. I know it'd not matter on linux/unix.

Comment: The file will have CR LF at the end of lines instead of just LF. If you have code that treats text files specially, then it can just removes the CRs.

Comment: @ikegami thanks, your answer will do. I wish you'd given it in "Answer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to read the file in text mode if it's a text file? You could use `binmode` unconditionally.

If you have a piece of code that deal with text files, it can filter out any extraneous carriage returns (0D). If you don't have a such a piece of code, then it surely doesn't matter if the carriage returns are left in.

Answer (score 2):

If you are paranoid about security, simply make sure to seperate executable files from data. `binmode` will not help you with this: It can be used to overcome line-ending horrors on DOS and descendants, and can be used to specify transparent encodings.

All User-uploaded files *are* hostile, for your concerns. There are no "safe" formats, so it is useless to seperate "binary" from "text" files. Do not trust simple heuristics. (E.g. Perl allows [control characters in variable names](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#The-Syntax-of-Variable-Names)!)

When processing user data, there are a few critical parts of Perl you should make sure no unchecked input reaches:

1. Regexes—arbitrary code can be executed via `(?{}) and (??{})`.
2. `system`, `exec`, `qx()`, backticks—self explanatory
3. `eval`—be careful when interpolating vars.
4. Other interesting points are arguments to `open`, `glob`, and the C-ish string functions.

`binmode` is not among these.

If you have to serve user specified data, try passing it through unprocessed. E.g. in case of an user defined stylesheet, that belongs into a directory where php does not interpret. In case of images, you could try to convert the file once received and save an equivalent, but probably safe variant.

Comment: Don't forget the tainted mode of Perl (-T). This won't take care of the holes, but will show you where they are -- where "tainted" variables are used in an unsecure context.

Comment: amon I'm not paranoid. I've have been attacked. I don't think you can type Control character in variables. You type caret for control chars.

Comment: @AgA I'm sorry if that was received as unfriendly, I didn't mean to offend. The perldoc (link in the answer) states: *"Perl variable names may also be a sequence of digits or **a single punctuation or control character**"* (emphasis mine). The caret notation just makes reading Perl easier without `vi`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on a modern POSIX system there is no difference between binary files and text files; a byte is a byte is a byte.

I would rather attempt another approach. If you use Linux / Unix, you can directly take advantage of the `file` utility which uses "magic" to peek into the first bytes (or further in some cases) of a file and determine its type; in Windows you will have to install it first. This utility makes it relatively simple to catch executables, zip files etc.

In Perl, you can use it through the module [File::Type](http://search.cpan.org/~pmison/File-Type-0.22/lib/File/Type.pm).

Comment: file utility works like -T/-B - checking only a block of text( the first few bytes only)

Comment: Yep; but either it had a .gif extension, and in that case it would not be executed; or it had a .php extension, and in that case it would be treated as any other php file from an untrusted source; or it had another extension, and it that case it should never be executed.

Comment: Moreover, in the case you are describing, searching for "invisible" bytes could also file; first the GIF header which as of specification does not require 0x0-0x1f, then normal php code.